# How to pass void pointer (starting of an array) to C function from Cython?

Tags: python, c, cython

I have a C function in write.h:

```
int write(int fd, void* arr, int size);
```

I have written write.pxd file to define it in Cython:

```
cdef extern from "write.h":
  int write(int fd, void* arr, int size)
```

Now, how do I write the write.pyx for its implementation. I tried this:

```
def write(int fd, void* buf, int size):
  return write(fd, buf, size)
```

But it complains that:

```
Cannot convert Python object argument to type 'void *'
```

How should I define so that I can send a list from Python and C gets the starting address of that list. For example, I want to call:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
write(fd, my_list, 3 * 4)
```

as `sizeof(int)` is 4.

Comment: The Python list is not an array of C ints. What you try to do cannot be done. But see https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/array.html

Comment: The duplicate I suggested isn't quite exact (given @AnttiHaapala's comment) but it is how you solve this problem. Use a proper array (numpy or `array.array`) rather than a Python list